# How is lack of tznius lifnei eiver?

Tags: women, tznius-modesty, lifnei-iver

Rabbi Ovadia Yosef, zt’l in Yechaveh Da’as III #67 indicates that a woman who dresses immodestly violates lifnei eiver.

How/why does a woman dressing immodestly transgress the prohibition of lifnei eiver? If it does not please cite sources to this effect as well.

Comment: We should recall that even if it used to be Lifnei Iver before such women could be found so commonly, and material which is _way_ more explicit is easily found in less time than it is taking me to write this comment, it might no longer be the case that such dress still violates lifnei iver. So pay attention to the dating of any source you bring.

Comment: @DoubleAA: http://www.dafyomi.org/index.php?masechta=avoda_zara&daf=6b&go=Go

Comment: מנין שלא יושיט אדם כוס של יין לנזיר ואבר מן החי לבני נח ת"ל ולפני עור לא תתן מכשול והא הכא דכי לא יהבינן ליה שקלי איהו וקעבר משום לפני עור לא תתן מכשול הב"ע דקאי בתרי עברי נהרא דיקא נמי דקתני לא יושיט ולא קתני לא יתן ש"מ

Comment: @SethJ It's way easier to find pornography nowadays than kosher wine, let alone a nazir to give it to.

Comment: @DoubleAA LOL, that may be true.

Answer (score 3):

Since a man is [prohibited](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/27099/may-a-woman-look-at-a-man-for-pleasure) to stare at a woman, dressing immodestly in front of men provides them with the tool to sin, let alone what the stare can lead to (improper thoughts, etc.) That seems almost self-evident, especially if she is doing it "to be seen". In other words doing it to draw attention to herself.

[I guess what is self evident to me isn't so self-evident to others. So let's start with adding in one more case of Lifnei Iver - a parent hitting an older child. The parent is in the room, all the tools needed are there. But he isn't violating Lifnei Iver just by being in the room. Rather by hitting the child, thus doing something that has a foreseeable consequence of motivating him to do an aveira, he violates Lifnei Iver. This seems to me to be directly analogous to a woman dressing untznius to be noticed. To clarify, I am speaking here about the fact that the untznius draws attention, so that would mean that not all levels of untznius draw attention (or cause hirrur) (e.g. a married woman with uncovered hair being the classic example), so that would limit the statement of when it is lifnei iver. And let me be further clear that I am not saying it is self evident that it violates Lifnei Iver, I'm saying that if it does, it is seems to me to be self evident because of this reason].

Double AA brings up a good point that for something to be Lifnei Iver it may have to be through providing something that was [otherwise unavailable](http://dafyomi.co.il/chulin/halachah/ch-hl-007.htm). Note that there are opinions that this is a Rabbinic prohibition regardless. It would also get into questions of what is "otherwise available" in this context (on the street, walking past teenagers, etc.).

Even if not, the common prayer every night is that no person should be punished because of me. So even if it weren't a technical problem (from Lifnei Iver), it still has an undesirable aspect to it.

Comment: According to this why should there be a difference what (or if) she wears? It's prohibited for a man to stare at her even clothed with the intent of getting pleasure. How can she walk outside? (IAE Please add sources; thus far your answer says "maybe".)

Comment: I never understood this type of argument. it is prohibited to stare at the little finger of a woman for benefit. does she need to cover her entire body? maybe women should not be allowed to stand still so that one can only look at them fleetingly. its also prohibited to say lashon hara so we should be prohibited from looking at any Jew lest we find a reason to say lashon hara about him. there must be something i'm missing

Comment: @DoubleAA, I think that may be an argument for dressing within the general norm (even non-Jewish norm, but something everyone is already used to, like the Aruch Hashulchan's argument about a married woman's uncovered hair) not being lifnei iver. But being untznius draws attention.

Comment: @Yishai I don't understand your point. Who cares if she is trying to draw attention? Is her action providing another with an opportunity to sin or not? Giving the Nazir wine is Lifnei Iver even if he ends up not drinking it, I would think. And by the way, sleeves just above the elbow do not draw attention unless you've spent your life in a hole.

Comment: @DoubleAA, regarding your modified comment to provide sources, Rabbi Ovadia Yosef is a source that it is. The question was to understand the opinion, which involves better definition of Lifnei Iver. It is not that you couldn't argue, but once you say it is, it seems pretty self-evident that this is the reason why.

Comment: @Yishai I mean source for "How/why does a woman dressing immodestly transgress the prohibition of lifnei eiver" not "Does she...". You haven't done that. (unless you are citing R Yosef's reason, which is not evident from your post) Self-evident or not I am more than entitled to seek sources.

Comment: @DoubleAA, indeed you are. I don't have a direct source for the point, I can only provide sources for the underlying ideas, and draw (what seem to me) to be obvious conclusions.

Comment: Are you claiming this is מסייע לעוברי עבירה according to the Ran (Commentary on the Rif, *Avoda Zara* 1b, הני מילי לענין איסורא דאורייתא אבל מ"מ מדרבנן מיהא אסור שהרי מחויב הוא להפרישו מאיסור והיאך יסייע ידי עוברי עבירה)?

Comment: @doubleAA if you look at the loshen it is staring at women but the first look is not assur,if you walk in the street and look up and see a women and don't look a second time or continue staring then there is no issur

Comment: @sam What's your point?

Comment: To your first comment

Comment: @sam Still don't see the point. If she walks out fully clothed then she is giving you the opportunity to stare intently and extensively and licentiously at her. Lifnei Iver.

Comment: My point is that to look is not assur it is the staring,she can walk outside but you should not stare at her its your problem that your staring ,but merely looking is fine.we might be going in circles ,not sure.

Comment: @sam And if she is walking around naked I also shouldn't stare at her...