# Must a woman not dressed for outside draw the blinds when standing next to a home window?

Tags: halacha, clothing, tznius-modesty

While cooking and cleaning in her kitchen, a woman wears clothing which she would not wear in public for reasons of modesty. The stove and sink face a window that faces a public street. Most people walking by on the street, do not stare into the house, but it is possible to do so, and people might stop to gaze. Is the woman required to draw the blinds or shade of the window lest people see her dressed immodestly?

Comment: As I understand it, the question is asking if someone needs to act as if they have no privacy in their own home because some people are peeping toms? Maybe people simply shouldn't go peering into others' houses. Related question: Is there any way in which  invading someone's privacy by staring in their windows permissible according to Halacha?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/18216/nudity-at-home \\ Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/13154/womans-hair-covering-in-the-home-or-in-private \\ Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/5552/married-woman-covering-hair

Comment: @Shmuel, dealing with "peeping Toms" is a separate problem. I can't imagine that there is any situation where it is "permissible". But humans are what they are, and if the opportunity is there, it's a "free show" and it's not illegal, people will peer no matter what. Knwoing that possibility, the question is how much precaution must you take. Or, should you assume that even if you live in an igloo, there is no privacy?

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/33293/how-is-lack-of-tznius-lifnei-eiver \\ I think this question is a dupe of a combination of these related questions. All issues asked here have already been addressed there.

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/38739/are-backyard-pools-against-halacha

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/14785/discussion-between-danf-and-shmuel).

Comment: http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=20023&st=&pgnum=61

Comment: I have picked up that there is an "indoor" standard of tznius that falls on the lenient side (tefach above the knee and elbow OK, etc.) whereas the outdoor standard follows the letter of the halacha or the minhag of the community, whichever is stricter--and most are strict on the tefach, stockings, etc. It seems that the "indoor" standard is OK in your own home even if guests are there, or so has been indicated to me by a LOR, in fact a LO Dayan, but check with your own. Not sure how this would relate to the window

Comment: @SAH You have elements to form an answer, I think, if you can get some clarity and combine these various ideas. My understanding, actually, is that tzniut applies in the same fashion both inside your home as well as outside. With the exception of the bedroom with husband and wife, and, of course, what's necessary to do in the bathroom. But, in such cases, one would have blinds, shades, or curtains, anyway.