# Does my wife have to wear a head covering and tzniut clothing while in the house?

Tags: tznius-modesty

If it's just my Wife and I and nobody else is home, can my wife wear clothing that isn't as modest? Assuming my wife is uncovered during relations, wouldn't that imply it's okay to have her knees, elbows, and collar bones showing (just in a casual sense, like when we aren't going out anywhere)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/13154/5323, http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38721/5323

Comment: @Shokhet that asks specifically about actual nudity. This, about modesty in general.

Comment: While I know that there are a variety of opinions on the topic, there is a rule that tzniut applies even within the inner confines of one's home. I haven't touched on the "mentoring" concept. much. But if you have children (even if all boys) and you want them and their families to observe a certain standard, you and your wife need to set the examples to build the foundations of that standard, whatever you choose it to be. In a busy community, it's probably a bit impractical not to be properly dressed at all times in case someone rings your doorbell, unexpectedly.

Comment: @mevaqesh Okay, that's why I said "Possible duplicate." My vote is not binding; we'll see how others vote.