# Why isn't there a prohibition of "Kol Ish" (man's voice) just like "Kol Ishah" (woman's voice)?

Tags: halacha, kol-isha

A recent question about Kol Isha got me thinking: why isn't there a similar "Kol Ish" prohibition against women hearing men sing?

If you've ever seen a teenage girl listening to pop music you'd know there's an attraction to a male voice.

I tried googling it and found nothing (besides an all-male acapella group called Kol Ish).

Comment: The halachos of _hirhurim_ (inappropriate thoughts) are less clear-cut for women than they are for men because women do not necessarily have a physical reaction to those thoughts. Nevertheless, it seems logical to me that women should avoid things that cause them to have inappropriate thoughts just like men should. For most women singing doesn't do that so there's no general prohibition, but if a particular man's voice does cause a particular woman (not his wife) to have sexual thoughts about him it seems very reasonable that she shouldn't listen to him.

Comment: @Matt elaborating on what Daniel was saying the avoidance of sexual thoughts is to avoid "wasting seed". This does not happen with women and so there are few if any rules about their sexual thought. Also note that whether this prohibition of listening to the voice apply always or just when reciting shema was debated by rishonim. Though it's generally accepted now that its always.

Comment: Maybe it is worth to ask a more general question about a-symmetry in sexuality and attraction b/w men and women.

Comment: So since women are incapable of "wasting seed" does that mean that female masturbation is not forbidden?

Comment: @Matt see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/56810/are-girls-allowed-to-touch-themselves there are several links from there in the comments as well.

Answer (score 1):

[Sefer Chasidim 614](https://www.sefaria.org/Sefer_Hasidim.614?lang=bi)

> מכל מה שכתוב בשיר השירים צריך להזהר שלא ישמע קול אשה והוא הדין לאשה שלא תשמע קול איש. שמכל שהאיש מוזהר האשה מוזהרת.‏
>   One must be careful from anything in Shir Hashirim, to not hear a woman's voice, and the same law to a woman to not hear a man's voice, for anything that a man is warned against a woman is [also] warned against.

Comment: So you're suggesting that it is forbidden? Does anybody observe that guideline?

Comment: -1 I think your answer is very incomplete. So you did find someone saying it is forbidden. Kudos! We all know SH is far from being the ruling Halachah, so albeit you do show that some prohibit you don't say anything about why the real Halachah does differentiate between the two.

Comment: @Al Berko Seems to work for Yevamot 84b. שהאשה מוזהרת על ידי האיש Well, sort of.

Answer (score 0):

On one level the answer may be that the derivative source for *kol isha* does not exist for *kol ish*. The issue of *kol isha* is presented in the Talmud ([Berachot 24a](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=1&daf=24&format=pdf)) as follows:

> א"ר יצחק טפח באשה ערוה למאי אילימא לאסתכולי בה והא א"ר ששת למה מנה
>   הכתוב תכשיטין שבחוץ עם תכשיטין שבפנים לומר לך כל המסתכל באצבע קטנה של
>   אשה כאילו מסתכל במקום התורף אלא באשתו ולק"ש אמר רב חסדא שוק באשה ערוה
>   שנאמר גלי שוק עברי נהרות וכתיב תגל ערותך וגם תראה חרפתך אמר שמואל קול
>   באשה ערוה שנא' כי קולך ערב ומראך נאוה אמר רב ששת שער באשה ערוה שנא'
>   שערך כעדר העזים
>
> R. Isaac said: A handbreadth [exposed] in a [married] woman
>   constitutes sexual incitement. In which way? Shall I say, if one gazes
>   at it? But has not R. Shesheth [already] said: Why did Scripture
>   enumerate the ornaments worn outside the clothes with those worn
>   inside? To tell you that if one gazes at the little finger of a woman,
>   it is as if he gazed at her secret place! — No, It means, in one's own
>   wife, and when he recites the Shema’. R. Hisda said: A woman's leg is
>   a sexual incitement, as it says. Uncover the leg, pass through the
>   rivers, and it says afterwards, Thy nakedness shall be uncovered, yea,
>   thy shame shall be seen. **Samuel said: A woman's voice is a sexual
>   incitement, as it says, For sweet is thy voice and thy countenance is
>   comely.** R. Shesheth said: A woman's hair is a sexual incitement, as
>   it says, Thy hair is as a flock of goats. ([Soncino translation](https://halakhah.com/pdf/zeraim/Berachoth.pdf))

As you can see in the part that I bolded, the verse cited by Samuel only refers to the voice of a woman, not the voice of a man.

Comment: Wouldn't that same passage then suggest men shouldn't look at women's faces (at least, if their countenances are comely, or as I found in a more modern translation, their faces are lovely)?

Comment: @Matt That would be included in looking at even the little finger.

Comment: It seems that your answer totally misses the point, because proving that Kol Ishah is forbidden says NOTHING about Kol Ish, maybe Gemmorah elsewhere says KI is also forbidden. I+1ed by mistake it but now I can't undo it.

Comment: @AlBerko The point of my answer is not to prove that kol ishah is forbidden. The question assumes that there is a difference between men and women and wants to know why. My answer is that the scriptural source used for women is not applicable to men.

Comment: @AlBerko I made an edit so that you can remove your upvote.

Comment: I don't understand where does it say this? It says "woman's voice is a sexual incitement", now what? How do you infer anything about men? Also the preceding part seems unnecessary, it adds nothing to the claim, I think.

Comment: (Even assuming that "sexual incitement" is the correct translation of *ervah*) it explicitly says immediately afterward "as it says..." The source that it cites is speaking about women not men. The reason I included the preceding part is to provide the context in which Samuel's statement was made.