# Tzniut sources for men

Tags: sources-mekorot, tznius-modesty, men-male

Does anyone know halachic sources or books that discuss tzniut for men? Can a women see the chest of a man?legs etc? What books deal with these issues, If any?

Comment: similar https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38747/759

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Ben! Consider learning more about the site from this useful short [Beginners' Guide](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/8775).

Comment: I recall a web article that summarizes some of the main points, esp. regarding the summer when men wear shorts and T-shirts and bathing suits. I'll have to dig around for it. In short (pun intended), it said that around the pool, men are unquestionably subject to the same tzni'ut rules as women, meaning that when going to and returning from the pool area, they must cover themselves with a shirt and / or a robe or towel.

Comment: There is a concept of Tzeniut for men but it is not because the women may not see the man uncovered, it is more of a man and god relationship. see SA OC beginning of siman 2 and mishna berura.

Answer (score 3):

[R. Moshe Feinstein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moshe_Feinstein) has a responsum about this. In [Igros Moshe Yoreh Deiah 3:68:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14677&st=&pgnum=319) he states that tznius for men does not contain any formal prohibitions, except when it comes to exposure of the genitalia, and is pretty much entirely dependent on local custom, and pietistic level.

Answer (score 1):

I note that the Sefer HaChinuch (387) posits that the commandment (Bamidbar 15:39) "you shall not wander after your hearts and after your eyes after which you are going astray", applies equally to both men and women.

It follows, that a woman should avoid having erotic thoughts from gazing at the uncovered areas of men.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question. You are quoting sefer chinuch about the obligation of guarding your eyes but this doesn't tell is in terms of tznous which parts of the male body must be covered and what parts may be uncovered. Since there is a prohibition for staring at uncovered parts this would imply there are two categories of body parts that 1. Must be covered. What are those? Also 2. May be uncovered. What are those could be answered by elimination in answering the first question

Comment: My comment was directed at the second question, "Can a women see the chest of a man?legs etc?" [Presumably of a man she is not allowed to be with sexually]. The answer IMHO, based on the Sefer Hachinuch, is that NO, IF it leads her to having erotic thoughts.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27099